# How to add a full working piece of website already coded, to a large scale Website design project?

Tags: php, customization, page-template, 404-error

I've written 5 PHP files each of which are dependant of each other and contains one `style.css` also. This whole project works fine when executed alone and includes `home.php` which includes HTML code for front end design and is also the home page.

But I wanted this 5 PHP files to be included as a part in my Large-Scale website design project so added whole of that folder under `C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\oceanwp\admin` where `admin` is the folder that contains my mini project (5 PHP files) which worked fine when placed in `C:\xampp\htdocs\admin` and surfing as `localhost\admin\login.php` (on Chrome Browser).

I've added `/*** Template Name: admin-login*/` to my `home.php`.

I have also added `admin-login` as Default Template to my Admin-Login Page on WOrdpress under `Page Attributes`
But on placing my mini project in `C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\oceanwp\admin` I was given a 404 Not Found error when browsed as `localhost\wordpress\admin\login.php`

Comment: I'd guess it's still under the wp-content path, so you'd need to browse localhost/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/admin.

Comment: Or if you want it at just /admin then you can probably set up some redirect rules in your web server, or hook into the rewrite / permalink URL handling in WordPress. Apologies I can't find the right API right now.

Comment: Please [merge your accounts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).